# No responses defined for platform: DIALOGFLOW_CONSOLE

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, dialogflow-es

I've had this problem for almost a day and I don't know what else to do to solve it.

Dialogflow Fulfillment in Dialogflow ES just doesn't want to make any HTTP calls at all. I'm always getting this error: No responses defined for platform: DIALOGFLOW_CONSOLE

My entired code is below. The function that crash everything is:

```
function simpleGet(requestUrl) {
axios.get(https://eo1lbzchsaeazi9.m.pipedream.net/)
.then(function (response) {
// handle success
console.log(response);
})
.catch(function (error) {
// handle error
console.log(error);
})
.then(function () {
// always executed
});
}

function simpleGet(requestUrl) {
axios.get(https://eo1lbzchsaeazi9.m.pipedream.net/)
.then(function (response) {
// handle success
console.log(response);
})
.catch(function (error) {
// handle error
console.log(error);
})
.then(function () {
// always executed
});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

sorry, there is some context missing here.

do you see the error message when trying to use `fullfilments` (ie. one API call to get on a backend an answer to a customer interaction?

Also, another clarifying question - is it Dialogflow ES or CX?

I've seen some developers struggling with this error and some of them fixed it by updating the package for fulfillments as described here: https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs/issues/322

Comment: Hi... I'm using fullfilments and Dialogflow ES.